# Is there a collection in standard Java for this specific task?

Tags: java, collections

So, I come across this idiom pretty often:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

  private static final Set<String> VALUES = new HashSet<String>();
  static {
    VALUES.add("good");
    VALUES.add("bad");
    VALUES.add("ugly");
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (VALUES.contains(args[0])) {
      System.out.println("Thumbs up for Sergio Leone!");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Whatever.");
    }
  }
}
```

A boolean output is produced of whether an input value (most likely a String) matches any of a fixed collection of values (most likely String constants or String literals).

I saw a couple of different implementations of this, such as:

- A boolean expression with or operators.
- An array of values + a foreach to cycle through for the matching one.
- Variant of the previous one: an array of values, sorted for Arrays.binarySearch().
- Using a Collection such as ArrayList or HashSet + contains(), see above.

I sense the lack of a common, optimal implementation here, since I encounter this kind of idiom a lot. Still, all of the above implementations feel like makeshift solutions. I wonder if:

a) The standard Java Collections framework already has a solution for such tasks.

b) If not, is there already a decent third-party implementation for this (such as some Apache Commons library).

Requirements (in order of importance):

- Optimal for a few dozen elements (versus sophisticated data structures such as hash tables / trees designed for quickly accessing millions of entries).
- Quick instantiation, small memory footprint.
- No obscure third-party dependencies, preferably built over pure Java.
- Also, in my case JRE 1.6 compliance is a must, although I'm also curious about solutions built on top of newer Java versions, too. (This means that pointing me to a JRE 1.8-based solution may earn an upvote, but not an answer mark, sorry.)
- After initialization (instantiation?) is done, it should be immutable - we only need to use it for contains()-like checks.
- Should throw an exception if we try to add a value redundantly upon initialization.

Comment: What do you mean by "most likely"? And whats wrong with HashSet?

Comment: Do you wont to instantiat them dynamicly, or as given by the example above staticly with the same values all the time? If it´s the later one then you could make use of an `enum`

Comment: @Sleiman Jneidi Most likely means, it should rather be optimized for small sizes versus millions of elements. This means it may still work with millions of elements if someone decided to use it for what it's not meant for, only it would be a poor decision based on performance considerations compared to estabilished collections such as HashSet, TreeSet, etc. To get a sense, see the sort implementations in Arrays, which often take array length into consideration when choosing an approach.

Comment: @Kevin Esche Static instantiation by rule. Using enums (+ enum fields, if necessary) may be a solution, yes.

Comment: @Sleiman Jneidi I do use HashSet all the time :-) I was just wondering if there's another solution, maybe something that is more efficient and/or more readable and/or more elegant. Hence the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JDK 9 it will be possible to do this:

```
Set<String> VALUES = Set.of("good", "bad", "ugly");
```

The resulting `Set` will be immutable, and this static factory method will throw an exception if given duplicate values.

(JDK 9 is not final as of this writing, and it is subject to change. See [JEP 269](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269) for more information about these new APIs.)

But you had also asked for a JDK 6 solution. I don't know what an "optimal" solution would be, since you didn't specify the critera that should be optimized. The `Set.contains()` method seems to have the right semantics for what you want, so I'll run with that.

It sounds like this occurs frequently enough that it's worthwhile creating a helper method to initialize the sets. Here's one that takes an array of strings and returns an unmodifiable set, throwing an exception if there are any duplicates:

```
static Set<String> init(String[] a) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a));
    if (set.size() != a.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate keys");
    }
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
}
```

Here's how you'd use it:

```
private static final String[] VALUE_ARRAY = { "good", "bad", "ugly" };
private static final Set<String> VALUES = init(VALUE_ARRAY);
```

The idea here is to use the nice array initializer syntax, while using the helper method to convert the array to a set while checking for duplicates.

A `HashSet` isn't the smallest data structure, but there aren't any obvious alternatives available without bringing in other libraries. If you're willing to trade time for space, you could create an unmodifiable `List` (probably just wrapping the result of `Arrays.asList`) and call `contains()` on that instead. This would give a nice compact array-based representation, but it degrades to linear instead of constant time lookup. Creating a `HashSet` would still be the easiest way to check for duplicates, but it'd only be temporary.

Answer (score 4):

Your `HashSet` solution is already using a `standard Java Collections framework` implementation, so I don't see any reason not to use it. If you want to make that `Set` immutable after initialization, you can add

```
VALUES = Collections.unmodifiableSet (VALUES);
```

after the initialization is done.

Of course you can reduce all that initialization to a single line of code if you find that more convenient :

```
private static final Set<String> VALUES = 
    Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("good","bad","ugly")));
```

Comment: "Optimal for a few dozen elements (versus sophisticated data structures such as hash tables / trees designed for quickly accessing millions of entries)."

Comment: @AttilaCsipak for searching an element in a tiny collection (a few dozen elements) you don't have to worry about performance. Worry about making your code as readable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with a handful of primitives or enums, it looks to me as though you want the switch statement, and not a data structure at all. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). Having said that you can't do it with Strings until java 7. It's an option to bear in mind for this sort of pattern though.

To give you an idea of the pattern:

```
int i = 0;
switch (i) {
      case 1:
      case 2:
      case 3:
          System.out.println("1,2,3");
          break;
      default:
          System.out.println("other");
}
```

I think this ticks a lot of boxes for you (although like the other posters, I don't share your concerns with HashSets).

Answer (score 1):

If the possible "Collection" of, i supposed they are arguments, are allways the same then you could possibly create an enum with the given possible arguments.
These would be created at compile time and would be immutable aswell.

```
public class ContainsTest {
    private enum Container {
        VAL1,
        VAL2,
        VAL3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String arg1 = "VAL1";
        String arg2 = "VAL4";
        if(ContainsTest.existsVal(arg1)) {
            System.out.println("Command " + arg1 + " is going to be executed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Command " + arg1 + " not aviable");
        }
        if(ContainsTest.existsVal(arg2)) {
            System.out.println("Command " + arg2 + " is going to be executed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Command " + arg2 + " not aviable");
        }

    }

    private static boolean existsVal(String arg) {
        try {
            // This method does check if an enum with the given arg exists
            Container.valueOf(arg);
            return true;
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // If it does not exist then an exception will occur that has to be caught.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks easy to enhance existVal() to accept custom enum classes as parameters. It only covers String types, so the HashMap solution suggested by other responses may be more flexible.